# API Call Requests and Responses increases 1 per click

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am Using Retrofit2 in application, using the `ServiceGenerator` class below.

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = " http://my.base.url";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .create();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        Retrofit retrofit = builder
                .client(httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor).build())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

And using the code to call API like below

```
final CatApi catApi = ServiceGenerator.createService(CatApi.class);
        catApi.getCats(catId).enqueue(new Callback<CatResp>() {
//codes success / failure methods
})
```

**Problem:**

First time I use this code. Getting log like below

```
 --> GET http://url.here http/1.1
--> END GET
<-- 200 OK http://url.here (4210ms)
<-- My Api Responce
```

Second Time I use ServiceGenerator Class for any API it shows log of two calls and two responses

```
 --> GET http://url.here http/1.1
    --> END GET
--> GET http://url.here http/1.1
    --> END GET
    <-- 200 OK http://url.here (4210ms)
    <-- My Api Responce 1
<-- END HTTP (3283-byte body)
 <-- 200 OK http://url.here (4210ms)
    <-- My Api Responce 2
<-- END HTTP (3283-byte body)
```

And the count of API calls increases like this one by one, each time I create a new API call.

All I need is a one API call and One Response. How can I find and resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you check, if `catApi` called for more than one time or not?

Comment: It's only calling once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
public static class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = " http://www.google.com";

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .create();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        Retrofit retrofit = builder
                .client(httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor).build())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

The problem is that you are keeping a static reference of your `OkHttpClient.Builder` and adding interceptor onto it every time `createService()` is called. Network call is being made just once, but multiple interceptors get added, which result in multiple logs.